# How to use deploy key of github in java git library

Tags: java, github

I am trying Jgit and Egit to raise PR using deploy key on github.com but I am unable to find a way to do it. There are no relevant documents present.
Can somebody point me to documentation or suggest some other java library to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of what you mean with PR but here is the documentation from github:

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

Comment: PR:Pull request. I am aware of the documentation. Wondering if any libraries can use it to cause changes in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/

deploy keys cannot be used for the API (only OAUTH keys can)

However, you can clone a repo with an OAUTH key according to this:

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#https-cloning-with-oauth-tokens

The only issue with this would be that the scope would be less restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I used a custom ssh dir `.ssh_github` to experiment freely without compromising my real ssh config.

**ssh config**

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh_github
$ cp ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh_github
$ cp ~/.ssh/config ~/.ssh_github
$ cd ~/.ssh_github
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C whatever@email.com
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/anne-ah/.ssh/id_rsa): id_rsa
```

If you just enter just the file name, the public/private key files will be generated in the current dir. You can enter a passphrase if you like, but can also leave it empty.

Get the public key...

```
$ cat id_rsa.pub
```

... and use it as the Github deploy key (you can leave the email address off, it doesn't matter)

It is important to have the github.com server key fingerprints in your `known_hosts` file. You can get them here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints . Simply append them all to the `known_hosts` file.

**Libraries**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0.202303070854-r</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0.202303070854-r</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java code**

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.TransportConfigCallback;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSessionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.sshd.SshdSessionFactoryBuilder;
import java.io.File;

class SshTransportConfigCallback implements TransportConfigCallback {
    SshdSessionFactory sshSessionFactory = new SshdSessionFactoryBuilder()
        .setHomeDirectory(new File("/home/johndoe/.ssh_github"))
        .setSshDirectory(new File("/home/johndoe/.ssh_github"))
        .build(null);

    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
    }
}
```

Get the ssh url for your repository and then you should be able to clone it:

```
Git.cloneRepository()
    .setDirectory(Files.createTempDirectory("my-repo").toFile())
    .setTransportConfigCallback(new SshTransportConfigCallback())
    .setURI("org-28603984@github.com:MyCompany/my-repo.git")
    .call();
```

It is not that hard, but it can be fiddly. And the sometimes vague and/or generic error messages do not help troubleshooting.